# Date retreival in android

Tags: android, date

In my application i have 1 edittext box,in this user will enter some date.What i want is i have to get the date of 7th day from the user entered date.I searched in google,i found 1 solution.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");                    
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add("field", +7);
String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
```

In the above `cal.add("field",+7)`-->Field is int.But my date format is string.So i cant use here..Please help me..

Comment: But how can you decide that user will enter in your desired format?

Comment: Thanks  Sameer..Thats second part..Consider user will enter in correct format..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get date from SimpleDateFormat and add this date object to calender then change into calender. And again get new Updated date from Calender. Wait i will post code

```
try {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date UserEnterDate = sdf.parse("String from your editbox");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(UserEnterDate);
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    day = day + 7;
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
    String newDate = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/"
                                + calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "/"
                                + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
```

Comment: +1 for ur help..Thanks sameer its working...Is any way to restrict the user to enter the date in particular format..

Comment: you have to use Input Filter.But i donot have code for it.you can Search on google

Answer (score 0):

```
As you said thatyou got the date in string format.
So let me start from there
Suppose the date is:
String dt = "2008-01-05";  // Start date
Then do thhis::   
     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
     Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
     try {
        c.setTime(sdf.parse(dt));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     c.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);  // number of days to add
     dt = sdf.format(c.getTime());
     System.out.println(""+dt);
```

Hope.this will definitely help you.
Enjoy!!!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest better you use `DatePickerDialog` in `onClick()` of `EditText`

then you will get individual Date Month Year.  Then you can set your date

```
Date+=7
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get Date Object from a String if you know the format, by your question the format is:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");                    
                       Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                       cal.add("field", +7);
                       String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
```

now use this date format to parse a string to get Date object, say:

```
Date dt=sdf.parse(txtDt.getText().toString());
```

now Set this date to Calendar Object:

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(dt);
```

now you need to add 7 days to this date, so do as:

```
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7);
```

now you have been added 7 days to the date successfully, now get Date from this Calendar object, by using:

```
Date dtNew=cal.getTime();
```

and you can convert it to readable string using:

```
String strNewDt=sdf.format(dtNew);
```

Comment: Thanks jeet..But i am getting somethink like this in my logcat..Its not error..but i didn't get result..               07-25 15:17:00.755: I/NotificationService(60): enqueueToast pkg=com.budget1 callback=android.app.ITransientNotification$Stub$Proxy@44d013a8 duration=1

Answer (score -1):

You have to write the name of the field you want to modify to the "field" parameter, here#s a link to the calendar reference. The calendar object is not a string, but a whole different creature that youre using. Use its functions to do it.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html

And so you would write

!edit, you actually have to set the calendar using ints and parse your string to match. use the set function from the calendar:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");                    
                   Calendar cal = new Calendar;
                   cal.set(int year, int month, int day, int hourOfDay, int minute)
                   cal.add(DATE, 7);
                   String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
```

Comment: DATE is an enum that is actually just the number 5 that matches the field that stores the day of month information inside the object. it tells the obejct to add 7 to the date, not to the month. The enums are also listed in the developer reference. Hope this helps.